# Magento 2: How to set first image of slider in fotorama js after cancel fullscreen popup in product detail page

Tags: magento2, products, fotorama-slider

Magento 2: How to set first image of product slider after cancel or exit fullscreen popup of image slider.

By default its display current selected image after exit popup in detail page.  I have to display first image of slider which is default image after page load.

Any help would be appericiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by extending the mage/gallery/gallery js module and then calling your JS in the template rather than the core gallery.js file.

Selecting the first element after closing an image can be done like so:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/gallery/gallery'
], function ($, Gallery) {
    'use strict';

    return Gallery.extend({

        initFullscreenSettings: function () {
            var settings = this.settings,
                self = this;

            this._super();

            settings.$gallery.on('fotorama:fullscreenexit', function () {
                settings.closeIcon.hide();
                settings.focusableStart.attr('tabindex', '-1');
                settings.focusableEnd.attr('tabindex', '-1');
                settings.api.updateOptions(settings.defaultConfig.options, true);
                settings.focusableStart.unbind('focusin', this._focusSwitcher);
                settings.focusableEnd.unbind('focusin', this._focusSwitcher);
                settings.closeIcon.hide();

                if (!_.isEqual(settings.activeBreakpoint, {}) && settings.breakpoints) {
                    settings.api.updateOptions(settings.activeBreakpoint.options, true);
                }
                settings.isFullscreen = false;
                settings.$element.data('gallery').updateOptions({
                    swipe: true
                });

                self.settings.api.first();
            });
        }
    });
});
```